# git cherry-pick from from feature branch, now rebasing against master loses all commits

Tags: git

I'm developing on a feature branch.  I committed something that should have been in master.  I checked out master and cherry-picked this commit and then pushed.  Back on the feature branch, if I rebase against master, I lose all my commits on the feature branch.   How to recover from this?

Comment: Just tried to reproduce your problem but I wasn't able to: I didn't loose any commits. Can you provide an example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I just tried replicating this in clean repo.  Couldn't do it.  Went back to my repo and tried again and this time nothing was lost.  I'm not sure what I did the first go around.  Thanks for the input.  I'm going to delete this question.

Comment: You could modify your question and generally ask how to recover a branch. This would probably be useful for others, too… :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the last commits you branch pointed to by using `git reflog feature_branch_name`. You can then do `git reset --hard <SHA>` on your feature branch to reset it to this commit.